# Should I build the chatting from scratch or buy a chatting api?

Tags: chat

I need teachers to send messages to the students and vice-versa? Should I and can I build something like that with average knowledge or should I use a chatting api on my website? I use php, mysql for back-end and for front-end standard languages.

Comment: It depends on how much custom functionality you need

Comment: @sina.ce I need basic text messaging functionality , filter messages like read,unread and that's all.

Comment: I think if you can use external API, it makes much more sense because of ease of implementation

Comment: @sina.ce Thanks for the answer. I've thought so.

Comment: your welcome, you can also use existing chat solutions like whatsapp and telegram and control their behavior via server APIs

Comment: I'm developing chat solutions for many years.
For live chat using PHP is a rather bad idea in the present days, because of the way it works. It's better to use a platform that acts as a server e.g. nodejs, java etc.
However, it's not impossible.
According to your question: it depends on your budget and requirements. Building a very simple chat server is an easy task, but each additional feature makes this task much more difficult.

Comment: @Antek Thanks for your insight. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a third party chat API because it will greatly speed up the time to build the chat messaging functionality.

have a look at [Minchat](https://minchat.io) which is a third party chat api.